# My passphrase doesn't work and I can't send any bitcoins from my wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, passphrase

When I encrypted my wallet, I created a passphrase and wrote it down very carefully. Now, when I try to make a payment to an address, I received the following message:
"Wallet unlock failed: The passphrase entered for the wallet was incorrect".

I copied and pasted the passphrase so I know it's correct, and yet I'm receiving the above message. Does this mean I lost all the bitcoin in my wallet? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try reverse caps as if you used CAPS LOCK in your keyboard ? If you got different keyboard layout like your native language and en perhaps it has switched etc... Indeed your passphrase is mandatory to recover your fund *unless* you backup your wallet before encrypting it. If you really take care during the process then it's probably something "obvious"

Answer (score 1):

> **Does this mean I lost all the bitcoin in my wallet?**

Possibly.

---

Try typing your passphrase into a text editor (notepad, vim, emacs, whatever) - If your caps-lock or keyboard settings are wrong you will see it.

If you are typing your wallet passphrase correctly and it is not accepted by your wallet then you almost certainly wrote it down wrong. You might be invoking the wrong wallet I suppose - maybe you tried out several wallets? Maybe on several devices?

In that case you should recreate your wallet on a different (but secure) computer using one of

- your earlier backups of the wallet.dat or equivalent file
- your safely written down private key
- your safely written down wallet recovery phrase (not applicable to bitcoin core)

Comment: The snark is unnecessary.